# Putting or Putting in?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is "in" needed here?

- > We simplify it by **putting** a coordinated effort.
- > We simplify it by **putting in** a coordinated effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. *put in* is a phrasal verb. See [***put in***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-in) def. 5:

> 5)  *(transitive)* to devote (time, effort, etc) to a task"   ⇒   *he **put in** three hours overtime last night*"

Alternately, you could say:

> We simplify it by *making* a coordinated effort.

Comment: Thanks. But will it be an error if we omit the 'in'?

Comment: @Ramnath Yes it will be. There are very few uses of *put* which do not require a locative or adverbial requirement.